# How to map one simple class(not an entity) with dto(Entity) class using jpa

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I tried @OneToOne Mapping with non @Entity class but it seems i am doing something wrong please help. Here is error log for the following classes.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on com.package.model.Hotel.address references an unknown entity: com.package.model.Address

Here is my ***Address.java***

```
private String street;
private String city;
private String state;
private int pincode;
private String country;
private String locationCoordinates;
//Getters and setters removed from the code
```

Here is my ***Hotel.java***

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String password;
private String name;
private String contactPerson;
private String email;
private String countryCode;
private long phone1;
private long phone2;

@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Address address;
private String description;
```

Address class is not @Entity class Only Hotel class have @Entity. Now i am trying to insert/create(table) data with the value of **Address.java** using spring and JPA into a single hotel table, And i am getting above complain in my Eclipse console.

Here is my RestController from where i am trying to get data

```
@Autowired
private RoomRepository roomRepository;
//RoomRepository is Interface which is extending JpaRepository

@GetMapping("hotels")
public List<Room> retriveAllHotels(){
    return roomRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: If your Address class is not an entity you should mark it as an embeddable instead

Comment: In Hotel.java mapping will be same? Marking Address class as @Embeddable did not help, Getting same error Hotel.address references an unknown entity: Address.

Any link or sample code will be very helpful. Thanks for the hint i am doing some googling :)

Comment: Got it, embeddable instead of Entity and embedded on reference worked. Solved thanks a lot @Brenin , Now working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

1. mark Address class as @Embeddable
2. mark link to Address in Hotel class as @Embedded
3. delete @OneToOne

and the Address fields will be a part of a Hotel entity

Comment: Yeah with the help of @Brenin comment I was able to solve my problem , this is exactly the stpes I followed to solve problem. Thanks